# eclipse cannot start without any error message

Tags: eclipse

windows 7, 32 bit, two jdk, one is 1.5, another is 1.7

I got two eclipse from my colleague, kelper and luna, they works fine.

I downloaded one from official site today, luna too, unzipped it, then double clicked eclipse.exe to open it. However, eclipse didn't run, there was no loading page as well as any error message.

I tried to add :

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\jdk1.7\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

to eclipse.ini, it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem recently when installing the Java 8 JDK in Windows, the installer appended a nonexistent Java location to my PATH variable. I'd make sure that PATH is set correctly and points to a valid JDK.

Comment: did you mean that maybe my eclipse points to a invalid path variable?

Comment: I mean the PATH environment variable, the one that appears if you type

    echo %PATH%

into the windows console.

For some reason, when I installed Java 8, the installer appended some sort of nonsense to the end of the PATH Variable, so that it no longer pointed to my JDK. Make sure your path to the "bin" folder in your JDK is in PATH, and remove anything from the end that looks like "Program Files/Oracle/Java" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Do install eclipse and jdk same platform specific.Install both either 32 bit or 64 bit..